# SQL - List of Last Transactions and Transaction previous to last

Tags: sql-server

What im trying to get is a list of the last transaction for every account which should total about 300. Then beside that i would like to list the previous transaction.

So i use the MAX(Transaction_Date) which bring back the list of last transactions fine. The problem is when i try to get the transaction previous to the last transaction.

It multiplies the results to about 4000 when the total should still be 300. There seems to be a problem with the join.

```
From Se2FAST.dbo.Cm_Opt_Poh_PolicyHdr_S CONT

    JOIN BASE BASE
        ON BASE.Poh_ID = CONT.POH_ID

    INNER JOIN Se2FAST.dbo.Cm_Opt_Pch_PolicyCovHdr_S policyCov 
        ON CONT.Poh_ID = policyCov.Pch_POLICYHDRID
        AND policycov.pch_sequence = 1  
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Cm_Sys_Pst_PolicyStatus_I] PST 
        ON PST.Pst_ID_I  = CONT.Poh_Status

    -- GETS THE LAST TRANSACTION

    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.DBO.CM_OPT_TXH_TRXHDR_S TRANS
        ON TRANS.TXH_POLICYHDRID = CONT.POH_ID

        AND TRANS.txh_effectivedate < ( SELECT MAX(TRAN1.txh_effectivedate) FROM se2Fast.DBO.CM_OPT_TXH_TRXHDR_S TRAN1 WHERE TRAN1.TXH_POLICYHDRID = CONT.POH_ID)                                      

    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Opt_Tre_TrxRes_S AS TRX_RES
        ON TRANS.Txh_ID = TRX_RES.Tre_TRXHDRID
    LEFT  JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Sys_Txt_TrxType_I TXN_DES
        ON TRANS.Txh_TRXTYPEID = TXN_DES.Txt_ID_I

    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Sys_Txs_TrxStatus_I TXN_STAT
        ON Trans.Txh_TRXSTATUS = TXN_STAT.Txs_ID_I

    -- GETS THE 2ND TO LAST TRANSACTION

    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.DBO.CM_OPT_TXH_TRXHDR_S TRANSX
        ON TRANSX.TXH_POLICYHDRID = CONT.POH_ID 
        AND TRANS.txh_effectivedate < (     SELECT MAX(TRANA.txh_effectivedate) 
                                            FROM se2Fast.DBO.CM_OPT_TXH_TRXHDR_S TRANA
                                            WHERE TRANA.TXH_POLICYHDRID = CONT.POH_ID
                                            AND TXN_STAT.Txs_DESCRIPTION_I  = 'Completed')

    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Sys_Txt_TrxType_I TXN_DESX
        ON TRANSX.Txh_TRXTYPEID = TXN_DESX.Txt_ID_I

    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Sys_Txs_TrxStatus_I TXN_STATX
        ON TransX.Txh_TRXSTATUS = TXN_STATX.Txs_ID_I
    LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Opt_Tre_TrxRes_S AS TRX_RESX
        ON TRANSX.Txh_ID = TRX_RESX.Tre_TRXHDRID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**:

```
;with cte as (
  select * /* cols go here*/
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by CONT.POH_ID
        order by TRANS.txh_effectivedate desc
        )
  From Se2FAST.dbo.Cm_Opt_Poh_PolicyHdr_S CONT
      JOIN BASE BASE
          ON BASE.Poh_ID = CONT.POH_ID
      INNER JOIN Se2FAST.dbo.Cm_Opt_Pch_PolicyCovHdr_S policyCov
          ON CONT.Poh_ID = policyCov.Pch_POLICYHDRID
          AND policycov.pch_sequence = 1
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[Cm_Sys_Pst_PolicyStatus_I] PST
          ON PST.Pst_ID_I  = CONT.Poh_Status
      -- GETS THE LAST TRANSACTION
      LEFT JOIN se2Fast.DBO.CM_OPT_TXH_TRXHDR_S TRANS
          ON TRANS.TXH_POLICYHDRID = CONT.POH_ID
          --AND TRANS.txh_effectivedate < (
          --SELECT MAX(TRAN1.txh_effectivedate)
          --FROM se2Fast.DBO.CM_OPT_TXH_TRXHDR_S TRAN1
          --WHERE TRAN1.TXH_POLICYHDRID = CONT.POH_ID)
      LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Opt_Tre_TrxRes_S AS TRX_RES
          ON TRANS.Txh_ID = TRX_RES.Tre_TRXHDRID
      LEFT  JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Sys_Txt_TrxType_I TXN_DES
          ON TRANS.Txh_TRXTYPEID = TXN_DES.Txt_ID_I
      LEFT JOIN se2Fast.dbo.Cm_Sys_Txs_TrxStatus_I TXN_STAT
          ON Trans.Txh_TRXSTATUS = TXN_STAT.Txs_ID_I
)
select *
from cte
where rn < 3
/* last and second to last will have
  rn of 1 and 2 respectively       */
```

for side by side:

```
select cte.*, cte2.*
from cte
  inner join cte as cte2
    on cte.POH_ID = cte2.POH_ID
      and  cte.rn = 1
      and cte2.rn = 2
```

Comment: I dont think its giving the results the way i want. I would like them side by side rather than in one column. transactiondate1, transactionstatus1, transactiondate2,transactionstatus2. Understand?

Comment: @ChrisM You could use a self join of the cte for that, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Weird. Getting "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value rn to data type int."

Comment: @ChrisM That's weird. I'd look for a typo or missing comma in the `select` of the cte.